# incorrect macro conversion to int when printing

Tags: c, octal

So I have the following code:

```
#define x 010000
```

My intention is to define x as '10000' in decimal but when I print out the above code it gets printed as 4096.
I dont understand how is that being translated to 4096.
Could anyone please explain?

Comment: When you write `int x = 0;`, you're writing an octal constant, not a decimal one (see C11 [§6.4.4.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1)).  A zero (not followed by `x` or `X` — or, in some circles, `b` or `B`) indicates an octal constant.

Comment: Darkfall, since you've been a member for nearly four years, on the off-chance you haven't actually read the help stuff yet, it's well worth doing: https://stackoverflow.com/help, specifically why some questions get closed (https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). That way, you'll know to search first to see if the question has already been asked and answered and you won't have to waste your time waiting for another answer or, more likely, getting shut down as a duplicate :-) This is not meant as criticism by the way, I'm just trying to help out a fellow traveler.

Comment: Yes, I understand this was a silly question and I should have looked for past answers before posting this. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers starting with a 0 are treated as octal in C. `010000` is an integer literal written in the octal notation. Its value is `8**4=4096`. Remove the first 0.

Comment: aah! yes ofcourse, thank you!